# Preloading ng-repeat with html

Tags: angularjs

I have a dilemma. - http://jsfiddle.net/o7b3r5pa/4/ *(ignore the error text, the fact that it just destroys the page is the issue. Notice how the div and textarea disappear, swallowed up by the library)*

This is what the library should do: https://jsfiddle.net/3o4y15qz/ *(See it sits nicely in the div as it was not loaded by javascript)*

**Overview:**

Someone's stupid library does not work when you use javascript to render it... It must be placed on the page before javascript runs. It basically renders a web form on the page for me so people can fill it out and it submits stuff to a system.

**The problem:**

```
<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    {{test.Content}}
</div>
```

I need to replace the above with this:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    <script>//stupid script library</script>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    <script>//stupid script library</script>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    <script>//stupid script library</script>
</div>
```

*The `<script>//stupid script library</script>` would be placed in by PHP and thus will work as they were not loaded by javascript.*

Obviously the issue is `ng-repeat`... I need it to be there, because i need to still let the divs have access for the `test.Left` commands. How do i get around this issue?

If i found out how to do this, it would allow me to place the content in via PHP and thus the stupid script library would then work correctly.

**---- EDIT ----**

I've tried to do the following:

```
...
$scope.Testers = [
    {
        "Content": "<iframe><html><body><script>alert( "hi" );<\/script></iframe></body></html>"
    }
]
...

<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    {{test.Content}}
</div>
```

But this still does not show anything inside.

Comment: Need more details ...that's why the question what does it do and what goes in that script tag?

Comment: If that script uses `document.write` it will not work at all since `document.write` wipes out a whole page if used after page load

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to show the issue with the stupid lib

Comment: Only possible workaround would be iframes. Open that script can see `document.write` which can only be used while initial page is rendering ..not after

Comment: Ooooo the joys of iframes, let me give that a try bro!

Comment: Or have 3rd party provide solution

Comment: If you control that script would be easy enough to modify to put into a directive and switch out the `document.write` for a more friendly dom insertion

Comment: Iframe also does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/o7b3r5pa/6/

Comment: I can't ever get those fiddles to even open enough to see the code

Comment: I'm using internet explorer... works fine here.

Comment: that render code and main script need to go inside the iframes to try to make it work

Comment: @charlietfl - Could you send me the jsfiddle you mean?

Comment: meaning iframe at each ng-repeat and that script tag needs to go inside iframe. Have been up all night ..sun coming up..not building fiddles for a while

Comment: I've tried for a while to place an iframe in the code, i'll provide an update above. This actually doesn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix 2 things. A good way to do will be create a directive that will use stupid library. Then do something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="test in Testers" ng-style="{ 'left': test.Left + 'px' }">
    <stupid-library-directive></stupid-library-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Stupid library must NOT be put in with javascript, it must be on the page before javascript gets time to go... AS it's a very stupid library.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 if it uses document.write it can not be used at all with angular